# How to use strings from class for language strings?

Tags: c#, class, multilingual

I want to realise an multilang in the app. I tried to create an class 'lang1.cs' in the project, then I created class, but I don't understand, how to use variables inside Form1 like MFAT.LngEnglish.About. My class for language stings:

```
namespace MFAT
{
    class LngEnglish
    {
        string About = "About";
    }
```

Comment: You'll have read [the fine manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/globalization-localization/) already, then?

Comment: In this case it's probably a more fundamental issue of attempting to access a non-`static` field..

Comment: In any case: ensure to include the *relevant [using] code* and *actual error indicator*. The compiler likely gives a helpful message.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create (e.g. within the constructor) an instance of the class then you can access the variable

Like this:

```
LngEnglish lngEnglish = new LngEnglish();
string about = lngEnglish.About;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a static class so that you do not need to instantiate a new object every time you need to access the strings.

For example:

```
namespace MFAT
{
    public static class LngEnglish
    {
        public static const string About = "About";
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
var aboutText = LngEnglish.About;
```